# JavaFX MediaPlayer "Error: 80de0001 in CallbackToJava..."

Tags: eclipse, events, callback, javafx, media

I am making a media player which allows users to drag and drop media thumbnails onto a media player (using JavaFX MediaPlayer).

When I run it and try the drag/drop functionality, some of the time it **works just** as **expected**. However sometimes it produces a *weird* error.

**The error in its fullness is:**

```
Error:80de0001 in CallbackToJava(javaIDs.View.notifyDragDrop, grfKeyState, pt, pdwEffect)
COM Error:80de0001 Unknown Error 0x80DE0001
Error:80de0001  in :: DoDragDrop( pcd, IDropSourcePtr(new GlassDropSource(obj), getDROPEFFECT(supportedActions, &performedDropEffect)
COM Error:80de0001  Unknown error 0x80DE0001
```

**The print-out in Eclipse looks like:** (all double-spaced)

[image: Eclipse screenshot of error]

I really have no idea why this is happening - I'm clearly doing something wrong. The error doesn't point me to any line of code. I would suggest that the error is referring to a memory address? Are you able to help me, please?

**The listeners/handlers which perform the Drag/Drop functionality are:**

```
    root.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            root.setStyle(highlightBackgroundStyle);
            parentScene.setCursor(Cursor.OPEN_HAND);
        }

    });

    root.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            root.setStyle(backgroundStyle);
            //parentScene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }

    });

    root.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            parentScene.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
            Dragboard db = parentScene.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

             ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
             content.putString(mediaFile.toURI().toString());
             db.setContent(content);
             arg0.consume();
        }

    });



    mediaPanel.getDropZoneA().setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent arg0) {
            mediaPanel.getMixerA().dragGraphicsOff();


            Dragboard db = arg0.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasString())
            {
                //System.out.println(db.getString());
                String mediaURI = db.getString();
                System.out.println(mediaURI);
                mediaPanel.getMixerA().getJfxMediaPlayer().loadAndPlayMediaA(new Media(mediaURI));
                mediaPanel.getMixerA().prepareMedia();

                arg0.setDropCompleted(true);
            }else{System.out.println("Drag error");arg0.setDropCompleted(false);}

            arg0.consume();
        }

    });

    mediaPanel.getDropZoneA().setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent arg0) {
            mediaPanel.getMixerA().dragGraphicsOff();              
            arg0.consume();
        }

    });


    mediaPanel.getDropZoneA().setOnDragOver(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent arg0) {
            mediaPanel.getMixerA().dragGraphicsOn();

            if (arg0.getGestureSource() != mediaPanel.getDropZoneB() && arg0.getDragboard().hasString())
            {
                arg0.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            }
            arg0.consume();
        }
    });
```

---

### Update 1

I am wondering whether this is caused by the way I 'change' the media for the MediaPlayer. I do the following:

```
public void loadAndPlayMediaA(Media playableMedia)
{
    if((player != null))
    {
        player.stop();
    }
    media = playableMedia;
    player = new MediaPlayer(media);

    player.play();
}
```

*I then immediately call:*

```
public void prepareMedia()
{

    view.setMediaPlayer(jfxMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer());
    view.setPreserveRatio(preserveRatio);
    view.setFitWidth(miniaturePlayerX);
    view.setFitHeight(miniaturePlayerY);
    playerSlider.setValue(0.0);

}
```

...The key line being `player = new MediaPlayer(media);`. I wonder whether occasionally I am hitting the split second where the MediaView is trying to get the next frame, but failing because the media has been re instantiated. (?)

**What's the best way to load up a new video?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you haven't found a solution yet...
I had the same problem and solved it by following code:

```
setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(DragEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("onDragDropped");
                    event.setDropCompleted(true);
                }
            });

setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(DragEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("onDragExited");
                    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                    ArrayList<Object> f = (ArrayList<Object>) db.getContent(DataFormat.FILES);
                    for(Object o:f)
                        System.out.println(o.getClass().getName() + ":" + o);
                    File file = (File) f.get(0);
                    newMedia(file.toURI());
                }
            });

setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(DragEvent event)
                {
                    System.out.println("onDragOver");
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                }
            });

public void newMedia(URI uri)
{
    m = new Media(uri.toASCIIString());
    mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
    mV = new MediaView(mp);


    mp.setOnReady(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mp.play();
        }
    });
}
```

In the DragDropped handler I call setDropCompleted to call the DragExited handler. Then I get the File out of the Dragboard and create a new MediaPlayerInstance. And then, you aren't allowed to call play immideately, else nothing will happen. You need to call play in the OnReady Handler, or at least after the MediaPlayer's status has been changed to Ready.
The Error will still appear, but it should work now ;)